# Get unique values of a dataframe for select input choices but only when the dataframe was defined in server.ui not globally

Tags: r, shiny

Example shiny app:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)


# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("example"),

   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 50,
                     value = 30),

      selectInput(inputId = "cut",
                  label = "cut",
                  # choices =  unique(diamonds$cut), # works
                  choices =  unique(my_diamonds$cut), # does not work
                  selected = "Ideal")

      ),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  my_diamonds <- diamonds

   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- my_diamonds$carat
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this case I am using a faux data frame 'my_diamonds'. In my real code I am connecting to a database using dbplyr and then making some transformations to it, so duplicating that in ui section seems wasteful.

What is the 'right' way to use a dataframe defined in server section to get the unique values, in this case `my_diamonds$cut` to use as a select input's drop down choices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using selectInput in the UI, you can instead use `UIoutput` in the UI and then define the UI element within the server function using `renderUI`.

So given that you have defined a UIOutput element called `otn_race_selection_op`, then we can define that as a selectInput object using the below code. Here getData is a reactive element that updates itself to the latest data. So based on that, you can modify the input choices for your selectInput object

```
output$otn_race_selection_op <- renderUI({


    df <- getData() 

    options <- sort(unique(df$Race))

    selectInput(
      inputId = "otn_race_selection",
      label = "Race",
      choices = c("All", options)
      ,
      selected = "All"
    )

  })
```